# Prevent image sliding when resizing window

Tags: wpf

I have two buttons with images inside like :

```
<Button Click="OpenIdFamily" Width="130" Margin="2">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="showId" Source="Resources/Logo/id.png" Height="25" UseLayoutRounding="True" />
        <TextBlock Text="Fiche identitée" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Padding="3,0,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

I got what I was expected but when I resize my window the image is sliding out of the button (see the two pictures)

[image: images are good] => while resizing => [image: Picture are sliding]

Thank you for your help !

**EDIT : The full GUI**

[image]

Here is my xaml code :

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Click="OpenIdFamily" Width="130" Margin="2">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image x:Name="showId" Source="Resources/Logo/id.png" Height="25" UseLayoutRounding="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock Text="Fiche identitée" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Padding="3,0,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Margin="2" Click="ShowHistoric" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="25"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image x:Name="ShowHistory" Height="25" Source="Resources/Logo/history.png" />
            <TextBlock Text="Historique" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="3,0,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Where you are placing the `Button`s ?

Comment: @Gopichandar Inside an Expander. I'll update my post with the full GUI

Comment: I assume that the button was placed inside the `Grid`, if that is the case, you have to modify the `Width` from `*` to some other `width`.

Comment: @Gopichandar I updated my code. they are in a single Grid with two row and one column. Thank you for your help

Comment: Windows 7 here... can't reproduce with your xaml.

Comment: @grek40 i'm with W7 too, it's just a windows style